# ExpressJS: Promises and Error Handling middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js

I have some error handling middleware defined and a route returning a promise. But when that promise gives an error, I have to manually append `.catch(err => next(err))` after every promise. While its not a problem, isn't it sensible for ExpressJs to see if a route returns a promise and if so call the error handling middleware automatically.

My current shortened code:

```
// errorHandlers.js
function sequelizeValidationError (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.name && err.name == 'SequelizeValidationError')
    res.status(400).send(err.errors)
  else next(err)
}

// auth.js
router.post ('/register',  middleware.isNotAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password, name } = req.body;

  return models.User.find({where : { email }}).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      if (user.password == password) sendToken(user.id, res);
      else res.sendStatus(401);
    } else {
      return models.User.create({
        email, password, name
      }).then(user => {
        sendToken(user.id, res);
      })
    }
  }).catch(next)
})

// index.js
router.use('/auth', require('./auth'))

router.use(errorHandlers.sequelizeValidationError)
```

For example, currently I could have forgot to write `catch` at one place and the server would have failed.

Am I missing out on something? How can I avoid having to type the `catch` every time?

Comment: Not sure if switching the framework is an option for you, but http://koajs.com/ works with promises natively. Writing a catching middleware is trivial in koa.js

Comment: @Herku , I cannot for this project, but will look at koa for the next project definitely. Took a look at it, looks quite easy to use with [koa-router](https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router)

Comment: There are various modules that provide promise support for Express, for example [`promise-express-router`](https://github.com/ufo22940268/promise-express-router) and [`express-ko`](https://github.com/ex-machine/express-ko) (which also happens to implement some Koa-goodness for Express). Perhaps it's of use.

Comment: @robertklep promise-express-router is good but lacks route-params and maybe some other features. IMHO its better to use a simple wrap function like the one in the answer instead . `express-ko` looks like a wrap function + generators . Thanks anyways

Comment: The modules mentioned above are hardly if at all used by any significant number of people in production and therefore are questionable at best to adopt moving forward.  Check the stars/watch count of each repository to identify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [already filed](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2259).

I had filed a [duplicate bug](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3031)

As of now the best bet seems to be to use a [wrap function](https://github.com/blakeembrey/async-middleware) .

Also see @robertklep 's comment above. [`promise-express-router`](https://github.com/ufo22940268/promise-express-router) may be useful if you donot use `route-params` . [`express-co`](https://github.com/ex-machine/express-ko) seems to be a wrap function + more generator-based goodness

Comment: Coming in Express v5 https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2259#issuecomment-433586394